# How to save a combination of images (svg + PNG) as one single image

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, svg, png

I have merged two images to make a single image in my application. The first image is an SVG image and the second is a mockup in PNG format both are joined to make a single image now I want to save the result on the interface as one single image as png or jpeg format is there any way in PHP or jquery for this

```
[<?=file_get_contents(base_url('assets/images/svg/'.$product->product_front_svg));?>
<div overlay="" overlay-id="overlayId" width="width" height="height" class="front_side kb-preview-overlay ng-isolate-scope" style=" background-image: url('<?=base_url('assets/images/svg/mockup/'.$product->product_mockup_front)?>'); background-repeat: no-repeat!important;"></div>][1]
```

The attatched image is a combination of two images (SVG image and PNG mockup) now i want to download it as a single image using php or jquery is there any wayout please tell.

Comment: Do you mean that the PNG is overlayed on top of the the SVG by using HTML/CSS?

Comment: where are your 2 images, i only see a array of some php and html, you may need a image processing library for this